# Jackson deserialise enum from a map of objects

Tags: java, jackson

So say we have a Pojo with a `Map<String, Object>` how do we tell Jackson objectmapper that some key names are actually enums and not Strings? For example the maps will not be equal as attr5 will be deserialised into a String instead of MyEnum.

```
public class App {

    enum MyEnum {

        A,
        B,
        C;

    }

    static class Pojo {

        private Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();

        public void setEntry(String key, Object value) {
            map.put(key, value);
        }

        public Map<String, Object> getMap() {
            return map;
        }

        public void setMap(Map<String, Object> map) {
            this.map = map;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

           ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

           Pojo pojo = new Pojo();
           pojo.setEntry("attr1", 1);
           pojo.setEntry("attr2", false);
           pojo.setEntry("attr3", "hello");
           pojo.setEntry("attr4", Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c"));
           pojo.setEntry("attr5", MyEnum.A);

           String pojoString = mapper.writeValueAsString(pojo);

           Pojo newPojo = mapper.readValue(pojoString, Pojo.class);

           System.out.println("Maps are equal: " + newPojo.getMap().equals(pojo.getMap()));
     }

}
```

Comment: You are serializing a `Map<String, Object>`. How do you expect Jackson to guess that it has to deserialize to an enum instead of a String? Use a class with proper types instead of a map

Comment: Had the problem of Maps and Enums too and switched to GSON (https://github.com/google/gson). It can handle Maps and Enums properly. Maybe it helps you too if you don't care using software of Google Inc.. :-)

Answer (score 0):

As fps said jackson is not able to distinguish enum from String inside Object.
In this case i will suggest to you to transport the type of the variable in json. It's quite simple and could satisfy your need. Please try :

Jackson configuration :

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
PolymorphicTypeValidator ptv = BasicPolymorphicTypeValidator
    .builder()
    .allowIfBaseType(Object.class)
    .build();
mapper.activateDefaultTyping(ptv, ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.JAVA_LANG_OBJECT);
```

Your json will look like :

```
{"map":{"attr5":["com.company.MyEnum","A"],"attr2":false,"attr1":1,"attr4":["java.util.Arrays$ArrayList",["a","b","c"]],"attr3":"hello"}}
```

It will add type information only to values in Map with Object type. Your test will pass as two maps will be equal.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to make a custom serializer for the map.

```
class CustomMapDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Map<String,Object>> {

    public CustomMapDeserializer() {
        this(null);
    }


    public CustomMapDeserializer(Class<?> vc) {
        super(vc);
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String,Object> deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt)
        throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        Map<String,Object> res = new LinkedHashMap<>();

        for(Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> n : jp.getCodec().readTree(jp).fields()){
            if(!n.getKey().equals("attr5")) //Only attr5 will be taken as enum
                res.put(n.getKey(),mapper.treeToValue(n.getValue(),Object.class))
            else
                res.put(n.getKey(),mapper.treeToValue(n.getValue(),MyEnum.class))
        }
        return res;
    }
}

class Pojo {

    @JsonDeserialize(using= CustomMapDeserializer.class)    //Apply Deserializer here
    private Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();

    public void setEntry(String key, Object value) {
        map.put(key, value);
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getMap() {
        return map;
    }

    public void setMap(Map<String, Object> map) {
        this.map = map;
    }

}

...
```